# Applying a dynamic image mask in Javascript/CSS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, mask

I have a horizontally scrolling collection of images. These are images of devices, that in theory have a shiny screen. As a user scrolls, I want to move a "light" across the screen to produce a "shine" effect on the screens of the devices. The issue is, I want to mask each device so that the "shine" overlay applies only to the device's screen, rather than the entire device image.

Please refer to the following video for an illustration of the effect I'm trying to achieve: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPkAp.jpg

My original thought is to have the gradient "shine" as a fixed overlay. As the page scrolls, I can move the position of the shine, no problem. But what I don't know how to do is mask the images such that ONLY the screens (shown red in the above video) receive the gradient overlay.

EDIT: the more I look into the `mask-image` css property, the more I think there will need to be an individual mask for each image.

Comment: This question is too open ended for StackOverflow. Questions without any code usually are. http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: Just to clarify - as a screen enters the viewport on the right a shine appears on its top left and as it movew across the viewport the shine moves down diagonally in a linear fashion to exactly disappear as the screen leaves the viewport to the left? Is that correct?

Comment: Please provide example code of some screens and them moving. In the real use case are they simple rectangles as shown in the video or are they photos of real screens?